# How do I identify an old water pipe vs an old gas pipe?

Tags: plumbing

My house in south Florida was built in 1959, with gas stove / dryer and I'm sure the tap water was pumped up from underground springs. During previous renovations, and city code updates everything was switched to electric and municiple water.
I'm trying to locate the old water pipe to connect a pump and sprinkler system to.
There are two capped pipes protruding from the cement slab just outside my kitchen door and I'm fairly positive one is the old gas line and the other is the old water line. How can I tell which is which? They were painted at some point so I don't know the color. Both seem to be the same size. Is there any way to tell?

Comment: I take it they're both steel pipes (thick walls) or does one appear to be a copper pipe with much thinner walls?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the water pipe will usually be galvanized or zinc coated. The gas is black iron pipe. If you scratch the paint off with a knife the galvanized will normally look brighter or shiny silver verses just a metal surface that may even be black in color thus the common term black iron. But the gas line is usually dull when scratched compared to galvanized.

Comment: Having never intentionally scraped at black iron pipe (the only stuff I've ever used was for bar clamps...) would trying to scrape the paint off of it also possibly/probably remove the black coating, or does the black go all the way through?

Comment: @freeman it is a layer of black oxide